# If I change the character set of a MySQL database, do I need to modify Ruby clients?

Tags: mysql, ruby, utf-8

I have a collection of ruby scripts that access my MySQL database.  I need to modify the character set for this database, specifically change the tables from Latin1 to UTF8.  Do I need to modify my scripts at all? I've looked and I see I can set the character set for a connection, is this mandatory?

Part of my hesitation in thinking I do not need to make any adjustments are the setting the database has today.  Looking at how character sets are already set up:

`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%char%";
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                    |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.21.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+`

wouldn't this suggest that clients are already set up to utilize a UTF8 character set?

Comment: Which library/gem are you using to connect to mysql?

Comment: Have you verified that the data in your tables is utf8-encoded?  `SELECT HEX(...)`.  My point is, that if you have garbage in the tables, fixing Ruby will be only part of your pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL manages encodings per client and per column. This means, every column in which text is stored has an encoding setting, and every connected client individually also has an encoding setting. Text encodings will be converted on the fly between these two as necessary. If a client sends UTF-8 data to be stored in an SJIS column, MySQL will make that conversion automatically (and the other way around on the way back out).

As such, it only really matters what encoding the client specifies when connecting to the database. If you're not specifying this explicitly in your Ruby code, you will get an implicit default setting. Changing the encoding of a MySQL column will not modify this default encoding. As such: nothing to do.

Comment: Well the encoding of the columns matters too - eg if the UTF8 data from the client contains data that can't be converted to the encoding used by the column

Comment: Well yes, it matters insofar as it determines what characters can be stored and how efficient the storage is. It doesn't matter at all for the client encoding though.